# assign multiple instances of a class to variables

Tags: python

Python. I need to assign multiple class instances to number of variables. First i tried this:

```
a = b = c = []
```

but they all refer to the same object, which is not what I need. This works better:

```
(a, b, c) = [[] for i in range(3)]
```

but it seems a bit too verbose. Is there a shorter way to do this?

UPDATE: OK, so this is not really Pythonic to cram everything into one line, question resolved.

But if this worked it'd be really cool:

```
a,b,c = []*3
```

And this line creates three references to the same object:

```
a,b,c = [[]] * 3
```

Oh well...

Comment: ok, so how about ` a=[];b=[];c=[]` if you don't want to refer to same object?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
a, b, c = [], [], []
```

Answer (score 8):

simply:

```
a = []
b = []
c = []
```

(python is not perl, there is no need for one-liners)

Comment: This communicates the intent to someone that is not a native Python programmer, so I like this snippet of code the most.

Answer (score 0):

```
a = []
b = a[:]
import copy
c = copy.copy(b)
```

You could use these if you want them all initialized to something other than []